# HP UFT, Square Bracket in XML Response

Tags: json, xml, qtp

I am using HP UFT 12.51, and is developing an API Automation script to test the XML response of a HTTP request. The URL will pass a set of IP from an Excel file to be verified and it will determine whether the IP is valid or not. When the IP is invalid, the XML & JSON result is as such:

XML: `<Error>Invalid IP address received in request : [202.1]</Error>`

JSON: `"Error":"Invalid IP address received in request : [202.1]"`

From the above the XML/JSON results have square brackets in it.

The expression that I used to verify the results is `Invalid IP address received in request : [{DataSource.GeoLoc!'InvalidIP-ITG$'.IP Address}]`

However when I did this I encountered an error because the square brackets are special characters, but when I put a backslash to the expression like this: `Invalid IP address received in request : \[{DataSource.GeoLoc!'InvalidIP-ITG$'.IP Address}\]`

This is the expected result I got: `"Invalid IP address received in request : \[202.1\]"` which does not match the actual XML result. It seems that when backslash is used not only the square brackets are being read as a normal character, but also the backslash itself.

Is there a way for the result to ignore the backslash and just read the square brackets in the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question but could you not just remove the backslash when you perform your check? i.e. use '***Replace***'